# is it possible to make accordion title navigate to a new page?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

i was wondering if i can make the title of an accordion a button as well without the button feeling?
here is a picture of the accordion title and some data inside it?
i want to click on the text that is in the title to navigate to a page...
using phonegap/cordova v1.9. Visual studio 2010 express for windows phone/html,CSS,javascript (c#)
 any help will be appreciated :) im open to a solution in anyway, including jquery's

[image]

title is
*inboxentry1 POS556445*

I have made the accordion in a bunch of div's that stacked into eachother...
tell me if i must add anything else to help with the solution!

here is some html for the accordion!

```
 <div id="AccordionContainer" class="AccordionContainer"></div>
    <div onclick="runAccordion(1)">
      <div class="Accordiontitle" onselectstart="return false;">
        <input type="button" href="ItemPages.html">inbox entry1</input>
        <br/>
        <a>POS556446x</a>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Accordion1Content" class="AccordionContent" style="background-color:white; color:grey;">
      <form>
        <p>
          <label for="create" >Created by :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:60px;" size="22" id="create"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="createdate" >Created Date :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:43px;" size="22" id="createdate"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="process" >Process name :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:36px;" size="22" id="process"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="transtype">Transaction type :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:20px;" size="22" id="transtype"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="lastact">Last action :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:61px;" size="22" id="lastact"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="lastuser">Last user :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:73px;" size="22" id="lastuser"/> 
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="lastupd">Last update :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:55px;" size="22" id="lastupd"/> 
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="duration">Duration :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:78px;" size="22" id="duration"/> 
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="saved">Saved :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:93px;" size="22" id="saved"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="adhoc">Ad hoc user :</label>
          <input type="text" style="margin-left:53px;" size="22" id="adhoc"/> 
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
```

here is my .js file

```
    var ContentHeight = 200;
  var TimeToSlide = 250.0;

  var openAccordion = '';

  function runAccordion(index) {
  var nID = "Accordion" + index + "Content";
  if (openAccordion == nID)
  nID = '';

  setTimeout("animate(" + new Date().getTime() + "," + TimeToSlide + ",'" + openAccordion + "','" + nID + "')", 33);

  openAccordion = nID;
  }

  function animate(lastTick, timeLeft, closingId, openingId) {
  var curTick = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;

  var opening = (openingId == '') ? null : document.getElementById(openingId);
  var closing = (closingId == '') ? null : document.getElementById(closingId);

  if (timeLeft <= elapsedTicks) {
  if (opening != null)
  opening.style.height = ContentHeight + 'px';

  if (closing != null) {
  closing.style.display = 'none';
  closing.style.height = '0px';
  }
  return;
  }

  timeLeft -= elapsedTicks;
  var newClosedHeight = Math.round((timeLeft / TimeToSlide) * ContentHeight);

  if (opening != null) {
  if (opening.style.display != 'block')
  opening.style.display = 'block';
  opening.style.height = (ContentHeight - newClosedHeight) + 'px';
  }

  if (closing != null)
  closing.style.height = newClosedHeight + 'px';

  setTimeout("animate(" + curTick + "," + timeLeft + ",'" + closingId + "','" + openingId + "')", 33);
  }
```

Comment: _this is my html only running now, no styling. so now you can see how i made the accordion, i only put in the fist title, seeing as all three of them look the same_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to make some changes here. A few classes have been added and the button tag changed as it wasn't correct. Your want to remove the inline event you have for the accordion and stick it where commmented below.

```
<div class="AccordionRun">
  <div class="Accordiontitle" onselectstart="return false;">
    <input class="AccordionLink" type="button" href="ItemPages.html" value="inbox entry1">
    <br/>
    <a>POS556446x</a>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can get it and add a click event to it...

```
var goToPage = function(elem) {
    elem.onclick = function() {
        alert('Go to page...');
        window.location = elem.href;
    };
};

var runAccordion = function(elem) {
    elem.onclick = function() {
        alert('Run Accordion...');
        // Your accordion code goes here...
    }; 
};

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].className == 'AccordionLink') {
       goToPage(buttons[i]);             
    }
}

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].className == 'AccordionRun') {
       runAccordion(divs[i]);             
    }
}
```

jsfiddle.net/FKt4K/2

Comment: Alex, this has helped me getting to a new page :) , but now my accordions wont open?

Comment: Alex is it possible for you to please post the previous code again please? i want to see what made it behave that way, because now my accordion opens, but the link don't work. Appreciate the help so far guys :)

Comment: Take a look at the following: http://jsfiddle.net/FKt4K/2/ If you click the title it fires accordion but should link after that and if you click anywhere else it should just be the accordion.

Comment: i cannot change the headings of the accordion, seeing as i have a class that makes it open and close! ... well maybe i should have shared that info ,so sorry, in edit you will see my .js file that initiates the accordion

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to navigate to an other page on click of an input field, here's a simpe work-around.. Just bind it to a mouseup-event like so (**needs a jQuery implemention**):

**UPDATED CODE**

**HTML:**

```
 <input class="followThisRel" type="button" rel="http://yoursite.com/">
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('input.followThisRel').on('click', function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('rel');
        window.location = url;
    });
})
```

Comment: _this looks like it just might work, but in the html Markup i dont understand what the href= is supposed to do?, and can i take rel= out? cause the page to go to is itempage.html_ i am new to this.

Comment: Can you tell me which accordion title should have this function? This "<div class="Accordiontitle" onselectstart="return false;">
" ??

Comment: the text for 
<input type="button" href="ItemPages.html">inbox entry1</input>
should be the "button" to click

Comment: @Arrie changed it.. is this what you imagined?

Comment: well i tried this but just nothing happened? is it possible to change the Rel="site", to maybe href="itempages.html", and in the jquery change the _.attr('rel');_ to _.attr('href');_ iam working on a live app, so i dont want to change a thing that could make me force to take it offline cause of my stupidity :)

Comment: and my @personName dont work for some reason,so sorry for that :)

Comment: well first of all, have you included the jQuery library?
if so, then I would first try it "attr('rel');". should this not work, you can do what you mentioned with ".attr('href');"..

Comment: also I updated the JS code.. wrapped the code in $(function() {})

Comment: yes i have the jquery core library in as well as the jquerymobile.js and the css of JQM. i am stumped, i have tried both of the mentioned approaches, and nothing :( ... the accordion keeps on opening, but no page navigation on title click... Alex's coding work on that example but not in my code